# Ayuda con sumar columnas de fila PHP, HTML, MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Buenas a todos tengo el siguiente problema espero me puedan ayudar

Estoy modificando unos campos los cuales ya me hace la sumatoria pero no se si este bien aplicado o sea lo mas correcto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como tengo los 12 o 24 campos

```
<label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Enero</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="enero" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $row["Enero"] ?>"></div>
```

Y en total tengo lo siguiente, lo cual me da la sumatoria automaticamente al cambiar algun valor y me le da formato de comas(,) y puntos(.)

```
<label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Total</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo number_format($row["Enero"]+$row["Febrero"]+$row["Marzo"]+$row["Abril"]+$row["Mayo"]+$row["Junio"]+$row["Julio"]+$row["Agosto"]+$row["Septiembre"]+$row["Octubre"]+$row["Noviembre"]+$row["Diciembre"],2, '.', ','); ?>"></div>
```

Si me hace la suma correcta de cada columna pero como le puedo hacer para que de esos 2 totales me saque el portentaje 3,001.00 * 100 / 15,002.20 = 20.00% en el siguiente input

```
<input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row[""] ?>">
```

Asi tengo asignadas las variables de Enero hasta Diciembre y de rem1 hasta rem12

`

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$enero = $_POST["enero"];
$febrero = $_POST["febrero"];
$rem1 = $_POST["rem1"];
$rem2 = $_POST["rem2"]; ?>
query("UPDATE clientes SET Enero='".$enero."', Febrero='".$febrero."', Rem1='".$rem1."', Rem2='".$rem2."' WHERE idCliente=".$idCliente);
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Como actualmente lo tienes resulta un poco cuesta arriba por lo que te recomiendo lo siguiente;

Creas un ciclo `foreach` para iterar el arreglo de los meses;

```php
$suma = 0;

foreach($row as $month){
    $suma += $month; //Iteramos todos los valores de los meses y lo guardamos en $suma
}

echo ;
```

Luego si quieres imprimir el valor;

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo number_format($suma,2, '.', ',') ?>"></div>
```

Si deseas realizar un calculo del porcentaje usuarias la variable `$suma` mas adelante;

```
<input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="">
```

Si deseas redondear a 2 decimales usa la funcion `round`;

```php
<?php 
   echo round(($suma / 3001.00) * 100,2); // Redondeado a 2 decimales.
?>
```

Comment: Que tal, gracias por tomarte tiempo en responder mi pregunta, en el ciclo foreach en la variable $month como guardo el valor de todos mis meses ahi? agrego codigo de mis variables a la pregunta

Comment: Esto que me preguntas es algo ya distinto a la pregunta inicial, si quisieras crearle un indice mas a ese array solo deberías hacer algo como `$month["total"] = $suma`

Comment: Intente con tu respuesta pero me sale el siguiente error Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Comment: uno de tus indices posee un valor no numérico en el array `$row`, podrias por favor hacer `var_dump(`$row`)` y publicar todo lo que sale en la pregunta?